# JQuery - On Click image open separate window

Tags: jquery, onclick

I am trying to open an image in a new tab when user clicks on the thumbnail, but even though I've tried many different solutions none of them worked.

I am posting jquery code:

```
$('#imagelink').click(function() {

     //location.href = $('#imagelink').attr("href"); //It is correct!
    // window.location.href = this.id + '.html'; //It is correct!
  //  window.open($('#imagelink').attr("href"), '_blank');
  //  $.winOpen($('#imagelink').attr("href"), "windowName", { fullscreen: "no", height: "600px", toolbar:    1, width: 600 }); //It is correct!
     window.location = $.myURL("index", $(this).attr("href"));//It is correct!

    });
```

As you can see I've tried all of the above five aspects and all of them open the image in the same tab which is not what I desire.

I am posting also the jquery code that includes also the html (this is included in separate file):

```
new_span.append('<a id="imagelink" href="'+ new.link +'"><img src="' + new.url +'" height=50px width="50px"  /></a>');
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with `target` as `_blank` like

```
new_span.append('<a id="imagelink" href="'+ new.link +'" target="_blank"><img src="' + new.url +'" height=50px width="50px"  /></a>');
```

Or you can also try with `javascript` using `window.open` like

```
$('#imagelink').click(function() {
    var URL = $.myURL("index", $(this).attr("href"));
    window.open(URL,'_blank','',''); 
});
```

Comment: Wow! It was just a piece of cake for you!! It worked! I'm quite newbie but I am trying to maintain and extend the project of another guy. Thank you a lot!

Comment: I do not know if I should raise a new question. But I have also tried to do it with hover. I mean when hovering over the thumbnail to see the actual image page. Actually this was the initial requirement, but I found it easier to start with click event. Could you also help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use :

```
target="_blank"
```

in your `a` tag.

If you want to follow jquery then use :

```
$('#imagelink').click(function() {
     var loc = $(this).attr("href");
     window.open(loc, '_blank');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following in the head section of your HTML.

```
<base target='_blank' />
```

If you want to open only the links of a particular section of your page then use th e following code

```
$('#my-Content a[href^="http://"]').attr("target", "_blank");
```

Here #my-Content is the id of the section in which your links are present.
This is for the anchor tags, but it works same with images too.

Comment: Thank you @srikanthbattula ! I have one more question if I would like while hovering over the thumbnail to get a frame with the actual size of the image, how should I do it? Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

according to your problem you just need a

```
target='_blank' //attribute for anchor tag.
new_span.append('<a id="imagelink" href="'+ new.link +'" target="_blank"><img src="' + new.url +'" height=50px width="50px"  /></a>');
```

even after appending this attribut you don't need explicit click function for it. you are attaching a click function it will open in popup window, some browser or you can say browser setting should be enable for popup. but target='_blank'  is enough to open a image in new tab. personally i don't recommend click function if you are providing a link in href.

but because you are newbie for your reference their are more attribute for anchor. that will help you in future.

```
_blank  Load in a new window
_self   Load in the same frame as it was clicked
_parent Load in the parent frameset
_top    Load in the full body of the window
```