# Open images in new windows on click event html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do masking of two images.
one image is predefined and second image is uploaded by user, I want to mask these two images in separate new window.

I am stuck here-

I am able to open one image in new window on click event([JQuery - On Click image open separate window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19903872/jquery-on-click-image-open-separate-window)). but not able to open two images.

Please guide me how can I open two images on button click event in separate new window or tab

My code-

```
     <a id="largeImage" onClick="swipe()">mask</a>

    <script>
     function swipe() {

       var url = "test1.jpg";

       window.open(url,'Image','_blank','','');

}
</script>
```

when I am using

```
    <script>
      function swipe() {

            var url = "test1.jpg";
            var url1 = "test2.jpg";

           window.open(url,'Image','_blank','','');
           window.open(url1,'Image','_blank','','');
       }
     </script>
```

it is opening only second image(test2 image overriding test1 image)

Comment: pls share the code with that you tried `HTML` & `JS`

Comment: @C P Verma Use `target= _blank` post your code it will help to solve the issue.

Comment: Call `window.open` 2 times.

Comment: can you show your code attempt

Comment: @NegiRox please check my code. I updated my question

Comment: @ShivKumarBaghel please take a look

Answer (score 0):

If you try something in event handler -

```
 window.open(URL1,'_blank','','');
 window.open(URL2,'_blank','','');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Actually you can't open two windows in single instinct.
You should also know that window.open is sometimes blocked by popup blockers or by ad-filters.  
instead you can use the iframe to acheive similiar thing.
here frame allows you to open multiple pages.

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a onclick="swipe()"></a>
    <iframe name="frame-1"></iframe>
    <iframe name="frame-2"></iframe>
    <script>
        function swipe() {
            var url = "test1.jpg";
            var url1 = "test2.jpg";
            window.open(url,'frame-1');
            window.open(url1,'frame-2');
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this fiddle I found:

You can *append* to body compiled element with binding, something like

```
$compile('<div>{{var}}</div>')($scope)
```

or you can add html to body itself and compile it

```
$compile(angular.element($scope.window.document.body).html('{{var}}'))($scope);
```

[Sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8atdw0t/57/)

Here's the link of source: [AngularJS: open new window and maintain two-way data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208711/angularjs-open-new-window-and-maintain-two-way-data-binding)